# Group a database data by some properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq

i would like to group some data given by a database by an Id like so:

```json
Suppose list A is like this:

Id: Description: Status:
1   Desc1        1
2   Desc2        2
1   Desc3        2  
3   Desc4        1
3   Desc5        2
```

Using LINQ how can i get a list like this one: (i suppose i have to use `GroupBy`?)

```json
List A sorted or grouped

Id: Description:
1   [Desc1, Desc3]
2   Desc2
3   [Desc4, Desc5]
```

Comment: Do you use some ORM? Please specify which one and it's version.

Comment: I don't specifically know if use or not ORM but for clarification i use Entity Framework Core to connect to a SQL database and retrieve the data that way.

Comment: Another thing is that i have a foreign key that links to another table so in my list i will have one property be an object. So therefore i can not simply use `query.GroupBy(x => x.Id)` i will have to create a new object like so: `query.GroupBy(x => new {x.AbilityId, x.PowerId})` then i could do the `.Select()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.GroupBy()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-6.0) with `Id` as key. And return a list of object(s) with `Id` and `Description` with an array of strings.

> Method syntax

```cs
var result = input.GroupBy(x => x.Id)
            .Select(x => new
            {
                Id = x.Key,
                Description = x.Select(y => y.Description).ToList()
            })
            .ToList();
```

Or

> Query syntax

```cs
var result = (from x in input
                group x by x.Id into g
                select new
                {
                    Id = g.Key,
                    Description = g.Select(y => y.Description).ToList()
                }
            ).ToList();
```

The above result returns list of `anonymous` object(s). Or map the result to your model class insted of using `anonymous`.

[.NET Fiddle Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Bq2Peu)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer but it seems like this kinda works but doesn't do what i need. Because i am making querys to a database using EF Core, and my table has a foreign key. So to reference the property in c# i had to use something like this: `public virtual Ability Ability { get; set; }` where `Ability` is another class. So i do not know how this would work in my code, but thanks again for the answer!